# Lint found a fatal error while assembling a release target

Tags: java, android-studio

I was compiling my app for release and I have received an error saying this:
    Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

```
<issue
    id="UnknownId"
    severity="Fatal"
    message="The id &quot;`_dynamic`&quot; is not defined anywhere."
    category="Correctness"
    priority="8"
    summary="Reference to an unknown id"
    explanation="The `@+id/` syntax refers to an existing id, or creates a new one if it has not already been defined elsewhere. However, this means that if you have a typo in your reference, or if the referred view no longer exists, you do not get a warning since the id will be created on demand. This check catches errors where you have renamed an id without updating all of the references to it."
    errorLine1="        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf=&quot;@+id/_dynamic&quot;"
    errorLine2="        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">
    <location
        file="C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\SafetyNet\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_mock.xml"
        line="35"
        column="9"/>
</issue>
```

Comment: You are having `id` problems; if you are certain that you have defined the `id`, then clean your project and rebuild

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There will be a more specific error in the logcat if you dig through it. If you can't see anything in the logcat, go to

`/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.xml`.

You will find the logs there. Post it in your question, if you still can't resolve it.

Comment: Sorry, is this the error? If so I'm afraid I'm terribly lost.

Comment: can you post your app//build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.xml file?

Comment: Its usually something very small.. Do you have translations in your app?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot find the file. I cannot find it in my directory? Is it there? https://imgur.com/a/zaNXChM

Comment: In your project navigation, click on the dropdown list which says `android` and select `project` instead. Then follow the path to `app//build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.xml`

Comment: I found the error thanks to your helpfulness.. but the error has me stumped

Comment: can you post it

Comment: Thanks, I found the file and it seems to be saying I'm referencing some _dynamic listview, which doesn't exist in the activity its mentioning. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using macbook just go to project directory and open build folder

search : "***lint-results-release-fatal***"
[image]


**Open** ***lint-results-release-fatal.html*** using safari/chrome and [image]


**Click** on the **Correctness** and it will show exactly what are the error
[image]


**Fix the error**
Then Try release again.

**All the best Good luck fellow developer**